# Excel - Is INDEX Volatile Here?

Tags: excel, indexing, volatile

If the data in the range `A1:C3` is this:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Then is the following formula volatile?

```
= SUMPRODUCT(INDEX(A1,1,1):INDEX(C3,1,1))
```

My guess is that it is volatile, since for example cell `B2` changing would mean the result of the formula would need to also change, even though `B2` is not part of any of the input ranges in the above formula. Or is Excel smart enough to realize that this formula would not need to be updated for any cell outside of the `A1:C3` range?

I realize this is a trivial example but the reason I am asking is because I am wondering this means that any version of `INDEX(...):INDEX(...)` is volatile.

Comment: http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsi.htm

Comment: No, it is not volatile, but Excel will mark the cell as dirty.  See [Excel Recalculation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687891.aspx) for more info.